# How to Assign User-Account Name and Directory to Array in Bash/sh?

Tags: bash, command-line, sh, rhel, user-accounts

I am attempting to create a bash script for the STIG test with the vulnerability ID V-72017 on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) system. I am tasked with making sure all user permissions have the octal value of 0750 or less

I have the ability to gather the permission octal value a user by using

```
    stat -c "%a" /home/$username
```

I am trying to create a $username (or directory) array by utilizing the command (outputs name of each user on the system):

```
    eval getent passwd {$(awk '/^UID_MIN/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)..$(awk '/^UID_MAX/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)} | cut -d: -f1
```

I plan to map this output to an array, possibly a while loop. Is this a possible solution?

Syntax Error from the following:

```
    (eval getent passwd {$(awk '/^UID_MIN/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)..$(awk '/^UID_MAX/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)} | cut -d: -f1) | while read -r line
    do
      myarray+=line
      stat -c "%a" /home/$line
    done
```

Desired Output Case 1:

```
    Users:
    rob
    bob
    Exit Fail: bob has permission octal value 0755.
```

Desired Output Case 2:

```
    Users:
    rob
    bob
    Exit Pass: All users have permission octal value of 0750 or less.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have found all login users. Regexp can be used to check home dir's permissions.

```
echo "Users: "                                                                   
(eval getent passwd {$(awk '/^UID_MIN/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)..$(awk '/^UID_MAX/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs)} | cut -d: -f1) | while read -r line
do                                                                               
  echo $line                                                                     
  perm=$(stat -c "%a" /home/$line)                                               
  [[ "$perm" =~ [0-7][0,1,4,5][0] ]] || echo "Exit fail: $line has permission octal value $perm"                                                                            
done
```

Maybe you want to adjust the output form.

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to avoid using `eval` as much as possible. All the more
if you are investigating the system security status. Please try the
following instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

perm=0750       # system policy
uid_min=$(sed -n '/^UID_MIN/ s/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' "/etc/login.defs")
uid_max=$(sed -n '/^UID_MAX/ s/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' "/etc/login.defs")

# read /etc/passwd and process line by line
while IFS=: read -ra a; do
    # now ${a[0]} holds username and ${a[2]} holds uid
    if (( ${a[2]} >= uid_min && ${a[2]} <= uid_max )); then
        # narrow down the users whose uid is within the range
        users+=("${a[0]}")
        # check the user's permission
        userperm="0$(stat -c "%a" "/home/${a[0]}")"
        if (( (~ perm) & userperm )); then
            # the user's permission exceeds the limitation $perm
            fail+=("$(printf "%s has permission octal value 0%o." "${a[0]}" "$userperm")")
        fi
    fi
done < "/etc/passwd"

echo "Users:"
for i in "${users[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done

if (( ${#fail[@]} == 0 )); then
    printf "Exit Pass: All users have permission octal value of 0%o or less.\n" "$perm"
else
    for i in "${fail[@]}"; do
        printf "Exit Fail: %s\n" "$i"
    done
fi
```

Hope this helps.